# When is $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[YX\mid X]}{X}$?

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

I have a bit of trouble understanding how I can work with moving that $X$ in and out of the expectation. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables in the same probability space.

Suppose $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X] = 0$ (I don't think this actually matters for my question).

Question: $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[YX\mid X]}{X}$, yes? (If $X$ and $Y$ are in the same probability space, this is always true? We need no additional assumptions?)

Is it also true that:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y_i\mid X_1,\cdots,X_N] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y_i X_i\mid X_1,\cdots,X_N] }{X_i}$$

where $Y_i$ is a RV, and so is $X_i$. Some clarification of this will help my intuition.

Comment: When you condition on $X$, everything that depends on $X$ can be take out of the expectation: $E(Yg(X)|X)=g(X)E(Y|X)$

Comment: I'd feel more confident about $X\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X] = \mathbb{E}[XY\mid X]$. Dividing by zero always makes me feel uneasy.

Comment: @Clem $\frac 0 0$ could make you uneasy, but $\frac x x=1$ should not.

Comment: Oh, it's correct. Still makes me cringe, as I have to read the expression and process it to recognize there is no such issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!

Safe to say:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X_{1},\cdots,X_{N},Z_{1},\cdots,Z_{N}] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y Z_{i} \mid X_{1},\cdots,X_{N},Z_{1},\cdots,Z_{N}]}{Z_{i}}$$

as well, yes? Or no?